# Reading csv file with pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzX11.jpg)I have a csv file with 2 columns which is text and boolean(y/n) where I am trying to put all the positive value in 1 file in 1 file and the negative one in the others. Here is what I tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('text_trait_with_binary_EXT.csv','rb',delimiter=',',quotechar='"')

#print(df)
df.columns = ["STATUS", "xEXT"]

positive = []
negative = []

for line in df:
    text = line[0].strip()

    if line[1].strip() == "y":
        positive.append(text)
    elif line[1].strip() == "n":
        negative.append(text)

print(positive)
print(negative)
```

And when I run this it just give an empty list!

I am new in using pandas so if any of you can help that would be great.

Comment: Can you post a small sample of the file? There is a much better way than iteration here.

Comment: Yes because `for line in df` does not iterate over the rows, just the column names. Please paste 5-10 lines of your file here edited as text IN YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: I added the screenshot and @thesilkworm already write the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have commented, there is almost always a better approach than using iteration in Pandas. It has a lot of built-in functions to help avoid loops.

If I understand your intentions correctly that you want to take the values from column 1 (named `'STATUS'`), split them according to whether the corresponding value in column 2 (named `'xEXT'`) is `'y'` or `'n'`, and generate two lists containing the column 1 values, the following should work (to be used after your first two lines of code you posted):

```
positive = df.loc[df['xEXT'].str.strip() == 'y', 'STATUS'].tolist()
negative = df.loc[df['xEXT'].str.strip() == 'n', 'STATUS'].tolist()
```

Here is a link to the documentation on [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), which is useful for problems like this.

The above solution assumes that your data has been read in correctly. If it does not work for you, please do as others have commented and add a small sample of your data so that we are able to try out our proposed solutions.